# How to bring up a separate view when a search bar is clicked? [SwfitUI]

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a search bar that brings up a separate view (see Twitter example).

[image: Gif showing twitter search bar animation]

How is this implemented? My initial thought was to somehow use a `NavigationView` to wrap around the search bar view, and when user clicks on the search bar, calls `NavigationLink` that'd bring up the separate view.

But is this the right way? The Twitter example doesn't seem to display `NavigationView` elements like the "< Back" button, nor does the animation transition match.

Comment: Twitter is probably using UIKit. In SwiftUI, you can key of the change of your `FocusState`.

Comment: Thank you, @Yrb. I thought `FocusState` is for shifting focuses to different textfields? How would you use that to control views? I couldn't find anything helpful from Apple's doc.

Comment: `FocusState` is a state, it defines whether something is focused, but others can bind to it and change it in response to actions. In this case, the action would be the user tapping a text field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FocusState` is a state, but it sets a variable. Therefore, you can key off that change with an `.onChange(of:perform:)` like this.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool
    ...
    var body: some View {
        TextField("TextField", text: $text)
                .focused($isFocused)
                .onChange(of: isFocused, perform: { newValue in
                    print("focus")
                })
        ...
    }
}
```

It won't work if you use it on other `TextFields`, but is will trigger on this.